# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder unable to rename

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Unable to rename MS Sharepoint folder.

Using **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder** object.

Any one help me how to Rename the current folder name. I am able to create/delete but fail to rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (objFolder != null)
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listitem = objFolder.ListItemAllFields;
                    listitem["FileLeafRef"] = NewFolderName;
                    listitem.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```